# Types of SSH connection error

Tags: ssh, terminal

I've got a Raspberry to which I normally connect via SSH. However, I've noticed different types of error over time that I've tried to connect to it. I want to know what makes them fundamentally different from each other rather than the obvious reason that it was a connection error.

Are there any more types of these? Can you point me to a resource that lists all of them?

[image]

Comment: These are all network-level errors indicating that the server wasn't reachable; the difference is how it realized it couldn't connect.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons for this happening. 
In the case of knowing what some of the errors are, there is a good resource [here](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/putty-manuals/0.68/Chapter10.html)